# Get columns size along with column name and datatype

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, linq, ado.net

I am trying to fetch columns, datatypes and size of columns of selected table and database from SQL Server database.

So far I am successful in fetching column names and datatypes but I want to fetch size also.

Example: Consider I have 2 columns in SQL Server database tables like below:

```
1) Name nvarchar(30)
3) Salary decimal(6,2)
```

Now I am able to fetch Name and salary with `nvarchar` and `salary` datatypes but size is not coming.

Code:

```
String[] columnRestrictions = new String[4];
columnRestrictions[0] = 'MyDb';
columnRestrictions[1] = 'dbo';
columnRestrictions[2] = 'Employee';
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionString"))
{
    con.Open();
    var columns = con.GetSchema("Columns", columnRestrictions).AsEnumerable()
        .Select(c => new (c[3].ToString(), c.Field<string>("DATA_TYPE"))).ToList();
```

Result I am getting is like below:

```
Name nvarchar
Salary decimal
```

Expected result:

```
1) Name nvarchar(30)
3) Salary decimal(6,2)
```

Source code: [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms136366(v=vs.110).aspx)

Is it possible to get above result?

Answer (score 1):

you can use **CHARACTER_OCTET_LENGTH** for char/varchar and the **Numeric_precision** + **Numeric_Scale** for numeric types.

Comment: Correct in general, except for char/nvarchar I would rather say using `character_maximum_length` column value.